# Discriminant of Elliptic curve $y^2=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I know the discriminant of the elliptic curve of the form $y^2=x^3+px^2+q x+r$ but how to calculate the discriminant if we have $y^2=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$?

Comment: If you divide through by $a$ you’ll have $(y/\sqrt(a))^2 = x^3 + px^2 + qx + r$ where $p,q,r = b/a, c/a, d/a$ respectively. This equation still describes the same curve, at least in a field containing $\sqrt(a)$.

Comment: I think there is some bi-rational transformation. The field is rationals here and the condition $\sqrt{a}$ is very restrictive if $a$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: If you write $y=a^2y'$ and $x=ax'$ your get an equation $y'^2=x'^3+\cdots$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. Now if the discriminant of the transformed equation is non-zero, it means that the original equation will be an elliptic curve, right?

Comment: The discriminant of elliptic curves is for Weierstrass equations, here you need to choose one, for example let $y=a^{1/2}Y$ and divide by $a$ (not the same as the one given by LordSharktheUnknown). The discriminant of $ f\in K[x]$ is the discriminant of $g=f/a_{\deg(f)}$, where $Disc(g)$ is a polynomial in the coefficients of $g$ but it is not homogeneous thus we can't extend it to a polynomial in the coefficients of $f$.

Comment: @reuns Now I am getting confused. So what should be the conditions on original curve to be an elliptic curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be "when does the equation $y^2 = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x +d$ define an elliptic curve"? Implicit I suppose is that you mean the corresponding projective curve for this affine model. The answer is precisely (assuming we are over a field of characteristic different $2$) when $a \ne 0$ and *the RHS does not have any repeated roots*, which should be the answer you are looking for. Assuming $a \ne 0$ (and is thus a unit) however, the cubic $f(x)$ has distinct roots if and only if $f(x)/a$ has distinct roots, since clearly they have the same roots. So you can then take the discriminant of this polynomial. Since you have to assume that $a \ne 0$, you may as well multiply the corresponding expression by a power of $a$ to be integral again, and so explicitly you get an elliptic curve if and only if

$$a (-b^2 c^2 + 4 a c^3 + 4 b^3 d - 18 a b c d + 27 a^2 d^2) \ne 0.$$

**Warning:** It is sloppy to talk about **the** the discriminant of an elliptic curve, which isn't really well defined. The discriminant is defined on a pair $(E,\omega)$ for some differential $\omega$ which generates $H^1(E,\Omega^1)$. In particular, if your elliptic curve is given in *Weierstrass form*, then it is traditional to take $\omega = dx/(2y)$, in which case $\Delta = \Delta(E,\omega)$ is $16$ times the discriminant of the monic cubic.

Comment: Integrating $\omega$ on the closed-loops $\subset E(\Bbb{C})$ gives a lattice and $\Delta(r(\Bbb{Z}+\tau\Bbb{Z})) =r^{-12}\Delta(\tau)$ from seing modular forms as homogeneous analytic functions on lattices. Taking $\omega=dx/y$ is natural for $y^2=4x^3+ax+b$ because it becomes $dz$ under the complex torus isomorphism given by $\wp$

Comment: From my computation, for the elliptic curve given by 
$$y^2 = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x +d,$$
 $\omega = a^{\frac{1}{6}}\frac{dx}{2y}$ (rather than  $\omega = \frac{dx}{2y}$) if you want that 
$$\Delta = \Delta(E,\omega)=16(-b^2 c^2 + 4 a c^3 + 4 b^3 d - 18 a b c d + 27 a^2 d^2) .$$ 
I'm still not sure if it's correct, since I don't have any reference except [Article by Deligne](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0097583.pdf), p59.